# Not disclosure file information to Excel users and avoid erasing other Workbook contents

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I would like to prevend users from finding out that there are password protected and VeryHidden Sheets in my workbook, named: "Sheet1", "Sheet2" ... "Sheet_n". Those sheets have also hidden columns, dependent formulas etc and I need to preserve all !

How to accomplish that ***without making the workbook unusable***? Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: @pnuts. I have read the link you suggested. Quite interesting. (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). **2nd paragraph:** "Faça perguntas práticas, que admitam respostas com base em problemas reais que tiver"; **4th paragraph:** "No entanto, se a sua motivação for “eu gostaria que outros me expliquem ______”, provavelmente está no lugar certo"; Considering that, in my humble point of view, I did not make a subjective question, on the contrary, I was very specific, **7th** and **8th** paragraphs do not apply. (continues ...)

Comment: @pnuts. I have a link for you too. (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer); **1st paragraph**: Graças a colegas prestativos como você podemos aprender juntos, como uma comunidade

Comment: Hello, does anybody know how to do it?